# Neo4j Cypher - Label Counts Returned in JSON Format

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the count of different labels in my db and return the results in a JSON format. The below query works to provide back the results I want but I can/t figure out how to format this as JSON. I've tried various variations of unwind and collect to no avail.

```
MATCH (e:entity) 
WITH DISTINCT LABELS(e) AS temp, COUNT(e) AS tempCnt 
UNWIND temp AS label 
RETURN label, sum(tempCnt)
```

I can get it to work just fine when I am looking for a particular label and its related labels (as per below) but I can't find a way to provide counts in the same JSON output when looking across the database.

```
MATCH (e:entity:Attribute),
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[:IS_RELATED_TO {current:true}]-(id:entity:infornite_com:Idiom)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[:CONTAINS {current:true}]-(da:entity:infornite_com:Dataset)
RETURN {
  numIdioms:  COUNT(DISTINCT id),
  numDatasets: COUNT(DISTINCT da),
  numAttributes: COUNT(DISTINCT e)

} as result
```

I want to have the first query but return in the format of the second query. Th closest I have gotten is the below:

```
MATCH (e:entity) 
WITH DISTINCT LABELS(e) AS temp, COUNT(e) AS tempCnt 
RETURN collect({node: temp, s:tempCnt}) AS rels
```

Comment: Have you tried `call db.stats.retrieve('GRAPH COUNTS')` or `call apoc.meta.stats()` if you have APOC Procedures? That will work for individual labels. It looks like you're trying to get counts for multilabeled nodes, so it may not help there.

Answer (score 0):

The following query may do what you want. It returns an array of objects. Each object has a distinct `label` value and its `sum`.

```
MATCH (e:entity) 
WITH DISTINCT LABELS(e) AS temp, COUNT(e) AS tempCnt 
UNWIND temp AS label
WITH {label: label, sum: SUM(tempCnt)} AS map
RETURN COLLECT(map) AS result
```

I was careful to mimic how your query calculates `tempCnt`, as you indicated it got the results you wanted. However, it is dangerous because the `LABELS` function returns a *list of strings* (since nodes can have multiple labels) in an undocumented order. Therefore, `tempCnt` actually is a count of how many nodes have exactly the same set of labels AND have those labels in the same order, as returned by `LABELS`. Nodes with the same labels can have their labels listed in different orders by `LABELS` (e.g., the order in which the labels were added may affect the ordering).

So, if you actually just wanted to find out how many distinct labels your `entity` nodes have, and also a count of the number of times those labels were used, @ChristopheWillemsen's answer would be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation from cybersam query, with an earlier unwind, tested on some database I have :

```
MATCH (n:TagOccurrence)
UNWIND labels(n) AS label
WITH distinct label, count(*) AS x
RETURN collect({label: label, count: x}) AS json


╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"json"                                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{"label":"NE_Money","count":2030},{"label":"NE_Person","count":83348}│
│,{"label":"NE_Time","count":598},{"label":"NE_Organization","count":37│
│184},{"label":"NE_Misc","count":22776},{"label":"TagOccurrence","count│
│":3008198},{"label":"NE_Date","count":32726},{"label":"Root","count":1│
│99026},{"label":"NE_Location","count":37852},{"label":"NE_Percent","co│
│unt":4494}]                                                           │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: If some nodes have multiple labels, the counts returned can differ from what the questioner's query would return. That is why my answer mimics how he calculates `tempCnt`.

Comment: I have added verbiage to my answer to explain further.